# Uninstalling default Mac OS X apps, like iCal, iChat

Tags: macos, uninstall

I just want to uninstall some Mac default applications, for example, iCal, FaceTime, iChat and so on.

That's because I do want to recover my free disk space from those things I will **never** use.

Is there any method to uninstall them?
I tried moving them into trash but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many OS X applications have hooks to others, so there's sort of a dependency. One good example is Mail.app and the calendar.

The application packages are only part of what you see—many of them have underlying frameworks in the `/System` folder. So, the `.app` files are probably just the tip of the iceberg and won't really make a drastic impact.<sup>*</sup>

The easiest way to save space in OS X is [to remove unused languages](http://monolingual.sourceforge.net/).

Other tips are mentioned here:

- [Freeing space on your Mac OS X startup disk](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/freeingspace.html)
- [MacRumors How to Free up drive space on an MacBook Air](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=15085059&postcount=2)

The single most important tip though is to avoid any sort of "cleaning" apps like MacKeeper, CleanMyMac, et cetera.

---

If you want to go for it, you can force-delete application packages by opening up Terminal.app, and then calling something like:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/iChat.app
```

However, do  this at your own risk. Keep a backup and don't complain the day you run into an error :)

<sub>* For example, Messages.app—the successor to iChat—uses around 26 MB. FaceTime is 5.4 MB.</sub>